# Improve dnn prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a processed dataset from the original NHANES. According to the available features, I need to perform a regression task, namely to determine the chronological age of a person (in general, I need to determine the biological age, but for now I stopped at the chronological one).

The problem is that I can't choose the right layers and their number, as well as hyperparameters, optimizers, loss and other (i tried many of them). I have been trying to do this for several days now, but to no avail. Maybe I'm doing something wrong or my data is too poorly correlated and this is the maximum I can get. In general, I need some advice from someone with more experience than I have. Any specific advice or tips would be appreciated, but thanks for any help.

Here is an example of input data (the last two columns are the calculated biological age by the KDM and its adjusted value. In the future, I need to calculate exactly these values, but for now I do not use them):

[image: example of input data]

Here is a sample code (I know this model is quite simple, but more complex variations show similarly poor results, similar situation with default loss functions like mae and mse):

```
# BA and BAC is biological age estimated using KDM method
# Need to estimate similar value without them
X = df_male.drop(columns=['Age', 'BA', 'BAC'])
y = df_male[['Age', 'BA', 'BAC']]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,
                                                    test_size=0.3,
                                                    random_state=20)

scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)


model_0_ha = Sequential([
    layers.BatchNormalization(input_shape=(X_train_scaled.shape[1],)),
    layers.Dense(50),
    layers.PReLU(),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.AlphaDropout(0.2),
    layers.Dense(25),
    layers.PReLU(),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Dense(1, activation='relu'),
])

optimizer = optimizers.experimental.Adamax(learning_rate=0.01)    

def max_mae_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    mae = K.abs(y_true - y_pred)
    max_mae = K.max(mae)
    min_mae = K.min(mae)
    return max_mae-min_mae


model_0_ha._name = "model_male_0_ha"

model_0_ha.compile(loss=max_mae_loss,
                  optimizer = optimizer,
                  metrics=[metrics.MeanSquaredError(),
                         metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()])

custom_metrics_callback = CustomMetricsCallback()
custom_metrics_callback.X_test = X_test_scaled
custom_metrics_callback.y_test = y_test['Age']
custom_metrics_callback.loss_name = 'CMASE'
custom_metrics_callback.epoch_count = 50

start_time = time.time()

history = model_0_ha.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train['Age'],
                         epochs=250,
                         batch_size=100,
                         callbacks=[custom_metrics_callback],
                         verbose=0)

end_time = time.time()
execution_time = end_time - start_time

prediction = model_0_ha.predict(X_test_scaled)
```

I've put my code and dataset on google colab, so you can try it at this [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1XDyBXh4Ez4dR4_i-qPKILiqJJT8cP3hp?usp=sharing) (if this resource allows such links).

Answer (score 1):

I have run your code multiple times, making modifications to the model architecture, adjusting the optimizer, and changing the loss function.

```
model_0_ha = Sequential([
    layers.BatchNormalization(input_shape=(X_train_scaled.shape[1],)),
    layers.Dense(50),
    layers.PReLU(),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.AlphaDropout(0.2),
    layers.Dense(25),
    layers.PReLU(),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Dense(1, activation='relu'),
])
optimizer = optimizers.experimental.Adam(learning_rate=0.1)
def max_mse_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean((y_true - y_pred)**2)
```

However, it turned out that the final MSE and MAE converged to approximately 144 and 9.2, respectively.

Here is my result.

```
Model results:
Time: 205.96876192092896 s.
MSE: 144.18941585132137
MAE: 9.241665510296738 | MAX:  57.41379356384277 | MIN:  6.103515625e-05
R2: 0.6252561398114401
|Real age       |Predicted      |
|---------------|---------------|
|21.000         |26.333         |
|35.000         |46.165         |
|48.000         |51.437         |
```

[image]

Given that your dataset is tabular type, it might be more beneficial to consider using tree-based machine learning models, such as XGBoost, Random Forest, or LightGBM.

For further insights, you can refer to this paper: '[Tabular Data: Deep Learning Is Not the Sole Solution.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1566253521002360?casa_token=cgdQncsPWjwAAAAA:m2mpWSn86x9slKm8n9exw9WRkEZEov5Psi1dA-Va_lr7Th5TdyKH0bQgsSGAhwx-djy918NwXg)'

Comment: Thanks for trying. Yes, I have already tested such models, they all show almost the same accuracy. Some a little worse, some a little better. I also tried converting it to CNN model and add LSTM layer, transforming the data to the appropriate form. But either I'm doing something wrong or it doesn't improve the accuracy.